# How to show product featured image only and hide product thumbnails on WooCommerce product page?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, product

I would like to show only the first image of product on the single product page (The featured one and the same small one). In other words, hide all images but not the featured image.

[image]

I know that I have to use `woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html` (or maybe not), I have tested:

```
function remove_featured_image($html, $attachment_id ) {
    global $post, $product;

    $featured_image = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );

    if ( $attachment_id == $featured_image )
        $html = '';

    return $html;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'remove_featured_image', 10, 2);
```

But it delete all images...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html` hook gets the featured image of the product.

**REMOVE PRODUCT THUMBNAILS**

You can remove the thumbnails from the single product page with this line:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );
```

*Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

You could also use CSS for this:

```
.flex-control-thumbs {
    display:none;
}
```

> But it's not the best choice. The images should not be hidden because
> extra HTTP requests would be useless. Better to do this via PHP if you
> have the option.

**EDIT PRODUCT THUMBNAILS**

Based on your comment:

You can edit product thumbnails via the **`woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html`** hook. This hook generates the HTML content of each thumbnail.

```
// hides all product thumbnails except the featured image
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'hide_thumbnails_except_featured_image', 99, 2 );
function hide_thumbnails_except_featured_image( $html, $attachment_id ) {

    global $product;
    $new_html = '';

    // gets the featured image of the product
    $featuted_image_id = $product->get_image_id();
    // hide all thumbnails except the featured image
    if ( $featuted_image_id != $attachment_id ) {
        $new_html = $html;
    }

    return $new_html;
}
```

> Thumbnails are automatically hidden if the only thumbnail is the
> featured image of the product.

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your theme's functions.php.*

**OVERRIDE TEMPLATE**

One last method is to override the WooCommerce template.

The template can be found in: `/woocommerce/single-product/product-thumbnails.php`

Comment: Hum... Thanks, but, I need to delete the second and next images of the gallery product, but not the principal image.  And with this line, it delete all image.

Comment: I have added an image to be more exact

Comment: Why is it important to display only one image (which is the same as the featured image)?

Comment: I need to hide the image that is surrounded on the picture, the featured image can stay visible, and the same small one too, but not the next images. 
And I can not use CSS because, I need to hide second and next images if the there is no authenticated user :)

Comment: I have updated my answer but it will not solve your problem. Try it yourself.